# Checking if a number is prime

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program in python that checks if a number is prime.

```
def isPrime(x):
   for i in range(2, int(x/2)+1):
       if (x%i) == 0:
           return False
           break
       else:
           return True
   if x == 2:
        return True

x = int(input("Enter an number: "))

prime = isPrime(x)

if prime:
    print(f"{x} is a prime number.")
else:
    print(f"{x} is not a prime number.")
```

The program works for most numbers. However it also recognises 27 as a prime number (which isn't true: 3x9=27).

Comment: You `return` in both branches of the `if`. `(x%i) == 0` if the first time it checks this condition it immediately return `True` and ends the function, since `27 % 2 == 0` is False and the else says `return True`.

Comment: The loop is never allowed to proceed past 2, so for any input higher than 2 your function is effectively just returning whether the input is odd or even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the lines

```
else:
   return True
```

It only checks if the given number is divisible by 2, if it is not, it immediately declares the number as a prime number. Removing those lines and rearranging a little should do the trick. You also have to add a return True at the end (Thanks [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11844224/andrew)).

```
def isPrime(x):
   for i in range(2, int(x/2)+1):
       if (x%i) == 0:
          return False
          break
   if x == 2:
        return True
   return True

x = int(input("Enter an number: "))

prime = isPrime(x)

if prime:
    print(f"{x} is a prime number.")
else:
    print(f"{x} is not a prime number.")
```

Comment: Er, only 2 is prime in this; huh?

Answer (score 0):

Close; here is the fixed code.  (There are better ways to do this, but this way works):

```
def isPrime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2, x):
        #print("testing %d against %d..." % (x, i))
        if (x%i) == 0:
            return False
    return True


x = int(input("Enter an number: "))


if isPrime(x):
    print("%d is a prime number." % x)
else:
    print("%d is not a prime number." % x)
```